# Stata: How to separate addresses in a string variable

Tags: split, stata

I have a string variable that contains addresses. How do I separate them so that I have address1, address2, ..., and so on?

For example:

```
7400 e roosevelt blvd # c201,philadelphia, pa 19152,7400 e roosevelt blvd # c201,philadelphia, pa 19152,7400 e roosevelt blvd # c201,philadelphia, pa 19152
```

I've tried `split` with comma but the results are not what I want.

Comment: As commas appear within addresses as well as between, that indeed won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do it:

```
clear
input strL many_addresses
"4905 Lakeway Dr, College Station, TX 77845"
"7400 e roosevelt blvd # c201,philadelphia, pa 19152,7400 e roosevelt blvd # c201,philadelphia, pa 19152,7400 e roosevelt blvd # c201,philadelphia, pa 19152"
"9514 John Dr. Sacramento, CA 95820,344 Cedar Street Alabaster, AL 35007,786 Maiden Avenue Windermere, FL 34786,154 3rd Ave. Lititz, PA 17543,7032 Sherman Road Buffalo, NY 14215,87 East Constitution St. Uniondale, NY 11553"
end
compress


/* (1) find where the two-letter state abbreviation and ZIP5 begin */
moss many_addresses, match("( [A-z][A-z] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])") regex
assert _count >=1 & !missing(_count)

/* (2) store the addresses in a1 - ak */
quietly sum _count
local max_addresses = r(max)
generate start = 0
forvalues v = 1/`max_addresses' {
    quietly generate a`v' = substr(many_addresses, start + 1, _pos`v' + 8 - start) if !missing(_match`v')
    quietly replace start = _pos`v'+ 9
}
drop _count _match* _pos* start
```

Here `moss` is from SSC and must be downloaded before you can use it:

```
ssc install moss
```

The basic idea is to

1. figure out the position(s) where the two-letter state abbreviation and ZIP5 start using regular expressions
2. chop up the long string into pieces once you know where to cut